# How to hint custom types for method parameters, where both the type and method is in the same class?

Tags: python, methods, types, parameters

How do I hint that the `symbol` parameter in the function `add_symbol`, is a type of `Lexer.symbol`? It says that it's not defined. I tried a few things and I don't know what will work.

```
class Lexer:
    class symbol:
        def __init__(self, lexeme: str, token: str):
            self.lexeme: str = lexeme
            self.token: str = token

    class SymbolTable:
        def __init__(self):
            self.symbols: list[Lexer.symbol] = [] # This works
            # self.symbols: list[symbol] = [] # This does not

        def add_symbol(self, symbol: Lexer.symbol): # This says undefined
            pass

        def add_symbols(self, symbol: list[symbol]): # This too
            pass
```

Should I declare the `symbol` class outside of the `Lexer` class instead? I kinda do want the it to be inside though. Thank you very much.

I tried it with and without the Lexer class to access the symbol, but it still says it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add
`from __future__ import annotations`
at the beginning of the file